# Quarkus k8s uses wrong properties file

Tags: kubernetes, quarkus, quarkus-rest-client

I have an odd one I think. I have a service that has three different config files for prod and staging and one as a base as well as dev:

[image]

In the prod version I have this entry:
`xxxx.confluence.private.url = http://xxxx-prod` while in the staging version I have this entry: `xxxx.confluence.private.url = http://xxxx-test`. When I execute my docker image in staging locally I have this output:

```
[io.quarkus] (main) Profile staging activated.
Sending request: http://xxxx-test
```

When I execute the same docker image on our k8s cluster I have this output:

```
[io.quarkus] (main) Profile staging activated.
Sending request: http://xxxx-prod
```

I set the profile using my deployment file using env variables:

```
env:
- name: QUARKUS_PROFILE
  value: staging
```

The prod.properties is the only place in my code which contains this specific line, meaning its definetly the one being used when resolving properties. Why does this happen and how can I change this behaviour?

Edit:

My entire deployment file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: calendar-service
  labels:
    app: calendar-service
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: calendar-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: calendar-service
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: calendar-service
        image: xxxx:k8s
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
            protocol: TCP
        env:
        - name: QUARKUS_PROFILE
          value: staging
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: xxxx
```

Comment: What does your k8s `Deployment` look like?

Comment: @geoand I added it, tho its quite short.

Comment: That looks correct... Do the logs also indicate that the `prod` profile is activated instead of `staging`?

Comment: No they do not, as you can see from the logs I posted in the question. There still somehow is a difference in the property files being used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This morning I restarted the deployment and it now appears to be working. I suspect there was some delay in our registry but I can not say for certain